Aspose docx for Java ReportingEngine cannot resolve method
I'm using Aspose Java to generate docx files based on a temaplte and I'm facing a problem on my generation.
I do this :
ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
engine.buildReport (templateDoc, resumedata, "resumedata");

Where resumedata (with lombok getter/setter) is:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResumeData {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String summary;
    private List<UserLanguage> userLanguage;
}

Then in my temaplte document I try to display information. I've tried several options but none of them work.
<<[resumedata.getSummary()]>>, <<[getSummary()]>>, <<[summary]>>.
None of them works. I've always the following error :
Api error 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An error has been encountered at the end of expression 'resumedata.getSummary()]>'. Can not resolve method 'getSummary' on type 'class com.mycompany.service.ResumeData'.


Just to add more information. When I convert my object to a JsonDataSource I have absolutly no problem to generate my document. Wich is really weird.

Data members should be public. You should modify your class like this:
public class ResumeData {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String summary;
    public List<UserLanguage> userLanguage;
}

And use the following syntax in the template:
<<[resumedata.summary]>>


Thank for help.
unfortunately, I already try this and get the same repsonse
An error has been encountered at the end of expression 'resumedata.summary]>'. Can not get the value of member 'resumedata' on type 'class company.appnam.service.ResumeData'
But I have notice that if i add the line
engine.setOptions(ReportBuildOptions.ALLOW_MISSING_MEMBERS); before the buildreport, I will generate my docx but without the summary. Wich lead me to think that my object still have a problem. But wich one ?

The above provided code and syntax works fine on my side with the latest 24.4 version of Aspose.Words.

For information, I have resolved my problem.
I was using
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
        <version>22.11</version>

the version was buggy. I upgraded to version 24.4 and everything works perfectly.
<version>24.4</version>

